# The axiom 5 of Peano guarantees that 1 is not the successor of any natural number, however large this be?

Tags: logic, induction, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

The fifth axiom of peano is the axiom of induction, I would like to know what happens in both cases, when zero is considered natural and when it is not. If this statement is true then why consider another axiom that says that 1 is not anyone's successor? I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

You want $0$ (if you include it) or $1$ (if you do not include $0$) not to be the successor of anything.  Otherwise you might have all the integers in your model.  That has to be an axiom of its own, not depend on induction.  Where it is in the order of the axioms depends on the presentation.

Comment: I don't see this.  If a set contains $0$ and is closed under the successor operation, then it contains all the integers?

Comment: @RossMillikan Okay, but then is the proposition true or false? And why?

Comment: @saulspatz:  it doesn't have to, but it could if $0$ were the successor of something.

Comment: @user402543:  any axiom is true in the system you are using.  Is that the proposition you were talking of?

Comment: @RossMillikan 
no, the one I'm talking about is "The axiom 5 of Peano guarantees that 1 is not the successor of any natural number"

Comment: No, the induction axiom is silent on this.  You need another axiom.  To use induction (assuming we accept $0$) you could say $0 \neq S(0)$, but then you can't do the inductive step.  From $0 \neq S(k)$ you cannot derive $0 \neq S(S(k))$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you just have the induction axiom and the three axioms that say that $0$ is a natural number, every natural number has a successor that is a natural number, and if two natural numbers have the same successor, then they are in fact the same natural number. (Replace $0$ by $1$ if you don’t include $0$ amongst the natural numbers.) Let $N=\{0\}$, and define the successor of $0$ to be $0$. This set $N$ with this successor function satisfies all of your axioms, but it obviously doesn’t match our intuitive notion of the natural numbers. The axiom that says that $0$ is not the successor of any natural number excludes this model.